# How to spilt data after year in excel?

Tags: excel

I have lot of data in excel, In every row I have values like this:

```
"Some text 2017 more text" 
"Some other text 2016 some more text"
```

and i want data like

```
"Some text 2017  |   more text"
" Some other text  2016 | some more text"
```

Now i want to split this text after year, Every row has year name in it but not at the same position, so I can't use the split tool. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the usage on [instr function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php)

Comment: thank @Alex but im new to excel , so i dont know much about vba.  is their any formula to do this ?..

Comment: There might be a work around, but does the "year" happens to be 2016 and 2017 only?

Comment: no, there are more year value too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only the 2010 decade (2010-2019 bdi) then please try:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("201",A1)+4,1,"|")
```

then Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top before Text to Columns with `|` as delimiter.